# Gradle failed to build when I run command with "./gradlew build"

Tags: java, gradle

I got gradle code from GitHub,when I build Gradle by command "./gradlew build".

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':reporting:reports'.
```

> Could not resolve jquery:jquery.min:1.11.0.
>     Required by:
>         org.gradle:reporting:2.9-20151003011703+0000
>   Could not resolve jquery:jquery.min:1.11.0.
>   Could not get resource '.../libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.xml'.
>   Could not GET '.../libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.xml'.
>   The target server failed to respond

I went to change the link to "'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js",but I do not know how to do.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: your gradle file would be helpful

Comment: You already asked the question on the gradle forums, and it's been tagged with "issue-acknowledged", so I think we can assume that it's a gradle issue, that has been acknowledged, and will thus be fixed. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-change-the-jquery-link/12011